# Can I substitute __func__ into an identifier name in a C macro?

Tags: c, macros

I'd like to write a C macro which takes this:

```
int foo() {
  MY_MACRO
}
```

and expands it to this:

```
int foo() {
  _macro_var_foo++;
}
```

I've found that I can't use `__func__`, because that doesn't actually get expanded in the macro; it's treated by the preprocessor like a variable.

Is there some way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't know about functions, just source files and line numbers. At that stage it's not performing syntactical analysis, just textual analysis and substitutions. That's why `__func__` is a magical variable instead of a magical macro like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: That's very sensible.  But my understanding is that GCC used to what I want.  I'm disappointed there's no way to get this feature anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In the C99 standard, `__func__` is given a special new category of 'predefined identifier' (in section 6.4.2.2 Predefined Identifiers):

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
>     static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function

This means that it is out of the scope of the C preprocessor, which is not aware of function boundaries or function names.  Further, it would expand to a string, which makes it inappropriate for embedding into a variable name.

---

The GCC (4.4.1) manual says in section 5.43 (Function Names as Strings):

> These identifiers [meaning `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`] are not preprocessor macros. In GCC 3.3 and earlier, in C only, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string literals; they could be used
>   to initialize char arrays, and they could be concatenated with other string literals. GCC
>   3.4 and later treat them as variables, like `__func__`. In C++, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` have always been variables.

If there was a way to get the function name into a preprocessor cleanly, then it is probable that the documentation here would have cross-referenced it, if it did not define it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [token concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation).

```
#define MY_MACRO(baz) _macro_var_##baz++;

#define FUNC_WRAPPER(bar)\
int bar()\
{\
    MY_MACRO(bar)\
}

FUNC_WRAPPER(foo)
```

The output from *gcc -E*:

```
int foo(){ _macro_var_foo++;}
```

Version dealing with argument lists using variadic macros and x macros:

```
#define MY_MACRO(baz) _macro_var_##baz++;

#define FUNC_DEF(ret_type,bar,...)\
ret_type bar(__VA_ARGS__)\
{\
    MY_MACRO(bar)\
    FUNC_CONTENTS\
}

#define FUNC_CONTENTS\
    printf("Do some stuff\n", s1, s2);
FUNC_DEF(int, foo, char *s1, char *s2)
#undef FUNC_CONTENT
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't concatenate `__func__` in a macro, because the preprocessor treats it like a variable.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you scrap usage of __func__ and instead pass the name of your function in to FUNC_WRAPPER(). Same result.

Comment: Oh sure, passing the function name to the macro is an option.  But I was hoping for something sexier. :)

Comment: @jonathan-leffler: dealing with argument lists is horrible as you can see! This solution is orthogonal however mismatches between the variadic arg list and the use of those args in the x macro is caught at compilation, not at the preprocessing stage. Not a huge problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer to your question is "yes", there is "some way". But I think you already knew that, and it's true that you cannot deal with this at the macro preprocessor level.

Sure, there is always a way, you just might need a really long tape on that Turing Machine.

I think you already know this, but *for the record* you can get the overall result you want with:

```
#define MY_MACRO f_dictionary(__func__, ADDONE);
```

So now, you just need to implement `f_dictionary` and an `ADDONE` op for it.

Comment: lol, yes.  But at that point, I might as well just type the function's name into the macro.  :)